# Databricks: configure R to use custom CRAN mirror by default

Tags: r, databricks, cran, sparkr, rprofile

I want to specify a default custom CRAN mirror in R under Databricks, but adjusting the config in the `Rprofile.site` file seems not to bet recognized at all.

I have already read the official Microsoft documentation on how to customize the R session in Databricks:

 [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sparkr/#r-session-customization](https://stackoverflow.com)

 The value of `R_HOME` is `/usr/lib/R`

So, I have adjusted my Databricks cluster-scoped init script which adds following lines to the `/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site` file:

```
local({
  options(repos = c(CRAN = "<my_custom_cran_url>"))
})
```

This works perfectly fine.
However if I run `getOption("repos")` within an R Notebook I get following output:

```
                         Cloud                           MRAN 
"https://cloud.r-project.org/"  "https://cran.microsoft.com/"
```

These are still the initial default CRAN settings.
This means, that they weren't overwritten by my custom CRAN URL in the `Rprofile.site` file.

If I run the lines mentioned above (`local({...repos...})`) in an R Notebook, the `getOption("repos")` will output the desired entry of:

```
                CRAN 
"<my_custom_cran_url>"
```

Maybe the file `/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site` is not executed at all although Microsoft is saying so?
Does anyone have a suggestion?

The Databricks Runtime version: `12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR :- Use the undocumented DATABRICKS_DEFAULT_R_REPOS environment variable and set the value to a ':' delimited list of repo URLs

For example

[image: DATABRICKS_DEFAULT_R_REPOS=file:///dbfs/FileStore/miniCRAN:https://cloud.r-project.org/]

I've also hit the same issue and I can confirm that `/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site` is being executed. Setting the option with a different name in Rprofile.site will show up in the Notebook.

The issue is there's another R profile script (`/local_disk0/tmp/_CleanRShell.*.r`) that is execute after Rprofile.site overwriting any repos options. Luckily this code is control by the DATABRICKS_DEFAULT_R_REPOS environment variable.

Comment: Thank you so much anth0ny-x!
The only problem I'm still facing is that my repo URL looks like this: `https://<username>:<password>@<my_custom_cran_url>`. In the script under `/local_disk0/tmp/_CleanRShell.*.r` I can see that the colon ":" acts as an URL separator. So it will separate my URL after the username. The only way I see to fix this is to edit the `_CleanRShell.*.r` script to use a different separator (for e.g. semicolon ";")